# Will Orchard CMS allow me to set role based editing rights on content?

Tags: orchardcms

I am evaluating different .Net CMS systems trying to find one that will work for my needs.
The main need that I have is to allow content areas to be edited by specific users in specific roles.
i.e. HR pages can only be edited by users in the HR role.

I've spent the day playing with a test site, reading docs and watching tutorial vids but can't seem to find how to make a content page or area editable by specific roles.

IS it possible or do I need to find a different CMS?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. For individual item permission control, you can enable content permissions. You can also set permissions per content type.

Comment: Content permissions sounds like exactly what I need but I'm not finding where that needs to be set/configured in my default installation.

Comment: Ok found it. It is  multi step process to enable content permissions on a page/content type.

Answer (score 0):

Under Modules/Security enable "Content Item Permissions"
Under Content Types choose your content type and add the "Content Itme Permissions" part to the content  type.
Then under Content choose your content type and "Enable Content Item access control".

From there you can set your permissions.